# "%+%" function returning NULL

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use %+% to concatenate. I am trying the following:

```
>nrow(myData)
1200
> a = "ORG_" %+% 1:nrow(myData)
```

I expect the results to be like:

```
ORG_1
ORG_2
ORG_3
.
.
.
ORG_1200
```

But, I am getting:

```
> a
NULL
```

Please help.

Comment: Where does this function come from? Just use `paste0`

Comment: dplyr does not define/export a `%+%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
a= "asdf"
b= "ghjk"

> a %+% b
Error in a %+% b : could not find function "%+%"
> a %stri+% b
[1] "asdfghjk"
```

Maybe it has been deprecated. You can use `%stri+%` instead. You could define it yourself though

```
`%+%` = function(x,y) x%stri+%y
> a %+% b
[1] "asdfghjk"
```